# Create a Laki language for Android keyboard

Tags: keyboard, languages, fonts

I want to create a language for Android keyboards, the language has many speakers in my country. The language is [Laki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laki_language).

I searched and found we have a Laki keyboard in Android, but it's not complete. So, I created a font for the Laki language and it works on Windows computers, and I wrote a book with this font.

I've created a custom keyboard for Android with this font and Kotlin, but it does not work because in Android we have default fonts, and my font does not work.

What did I find? I found ASCII code for languages.

How can I create an ASCII for my language and with that, I create a custom keyboard?

Comment: If the letter you need are not included in Ascii you need to search for the relevant character in Unicode. Of course you then also need a font that contains the Unicode characters you want to use.

Comment: Note that app development is off-topic since Android Enthusiasts focuses on end-users or power-users (but not necessarily developers) solving their issues. We probably can give hints on what's missing (e.g. replacing the system font to make it work), but we can't help with coding issues.